# ¿Como insertar varios productos, en diferentes registros en una misma tabla?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

Buenas tardes estimados amigos, necesito por favor que me ayuden si es posible con este problema que no le hallo solución, si no es molestia, y gracias de antemano por su ayuda, consejos, u orientación.

El tema es que estoy realizando un Punto de Venta(POS), y estoy desarrollando el módulo de compras del sistema, dicho módulo está planteado en ajax pues el proceso es el siguiente:

1. Al cliquear el botón realizar compra deberán insertarse a la base de datos por ajax tantos registros tenga la tabla HTML- y es aquí donde viene mi pregunta.

¿Como hacer para que al realizar la compra, se registren en la base de datos con un mismo número de transacción pero en rows diferentes los productos que compré?
Ej:

Para 3 productos de la tabla HTML, cargada con la INFO del formulario.

```
ID | NROTRANS | PRODUCTO
1        1         1
2        1         2
3        1         3
```

**SOLUCIÓN más sencilla**

Bueno encontré la solución por fin, lo que hice fue cambiar un poco la lógica de carga de productos, antes había que cargar los todos productos a la tabla a través de jquery, y al finalizar la compra es que se insertaban las múltiples rows a la base de datos.

Lo que hice fue que ahora cada vez que lleno el formulario, hago submit, rescato por get la $_SESSION del proveedor al cual le estoy comprando y con header location redirijo con ese parámetro a la misma página, y evalúo si el parámetro está presente en la URL, si es así cargo todos los productos asociados a ese proveedor proveniente de la tabla acsi_posprecompra, y los listo en un table.

Al finalizar la compra, se buscan los registros asociados a ese proveedor en la tabla acsi_posprecompra, se recorren los registros por un ciclo while y se insertan secuencialmente en la tabla acsi_postransacciones, después de haber terminado el proceso, se hace un DELETE a todos los registros asociados a ese proveedor en la tabla acsi_posprecompra.

Perdonen por no colocar todo el código, ustedes comprenderán que es extenso...

Gracias a Hammerfall por responder, lo intenté como propusiste pero al final no era lo que querían ellos... Pero igual fue una respuesta valida, trabajarlo con arrays.

Comment: Primero se inserta la transacción, los productos forman parte del detalle, en un esquema ER transacción es padre de detalle, por lo que deberas hacer `INSERT INTO transacciones`, obtener el id de dicha transacción para añadirlo en los detalles de esta.

Comment: @HammerffallBK Gracias por tu respuesta amigo, lo que ocurre es que lo que se quiere, es que se ingrese un registro por transacción, es decir si compras 10 productos en la misma compra, deben haber 10 registros en la tabla con el mismo NROTRANS.

Comment: como añades tus productos, haces una busqueda y agregas los inputs que contienen el id, cantidad, descuento, todo dentro del mismo formulario. Si tu transacción se genera en el momento que haces POST de todos los datos (tanto transacción y productos), entonces primero insertas en la tabla transacción y obtienes ese id insertado, y haces un recorrido de productos para insertarlos con el mismo número de transacción

Comment: @HammerffallBK Me disculpo por no ser más específico.

Los campos de la factura de compra están dentro de un mismo formulario html. 

Buscas el código del producto a través de ajax, te devuelve como respuesta el nombre del producto, e ingresas cantidad y precio unitario manualmente, al pulsar enter se vacían los campos de formulario compra y la info va a una tabla html más abajo, que es como un carrito de compra, dichos productos quedan pendientes por grabar. 

Lo que quiero es insertar los 'n' productos agregados a la tabla html carrito, como registros independientes a la base de datos.

Comment: @HammerffallBK El insert se hace al cliquear el botón Purchase, que dispara la petición ajax y envía por post los datos del formulario. Como te dije deben insertarse tantas rows como tenga la tabla html con su respectiva info y el NRO de Transacción es el mismo para esa compra. Todo en la misma tabla acsi_postransacciones.

Comment: Como registros independientes te refieres a que no estén ligados a una transacción?

Comment: @HammerffallBK Nope, deben estar ligados a esa transacción, es que te explico, llenas los campos, y jquery añade una fila a la tabla html, la cantidad y precio de ese producto, y lo pone pendiente para grabar, si ingresas otro producto, genera otra fila debajo con la información de ese otro producto, recordar que estás en la misma compra, y que sólo al darle comprar se envían esos productos a la base de datos, por lo que si agregaste 10 items antes de comprar, al insertarse deben ir 10 registros con el mismo nro de transacción y los 10 productos distintos que compraste.

Comment: Observa en el ejemplo de la pregunta jeje, en resumen al insertar verías en la tabla de la base de datos, 10 registros con el auto_increment del 1 al 10, cada registro con su producto individual y el mismo número de transacción.

Comment: Si entiendo, coloca la parte del código donde recibes el request y haces la insercción a la base de datos para poder ayudarte y como lo agregas con jquery para ver que es lo que haces

Comment: @HammerffallBK Listo bro, cualquier duda con el código estoy pendiente :), cabe destacar que las conexiones a la base de datos están más arriba en el mismo archivo, por eso no las coloqué.

Comment: Coloca el código de como agregas los productos con ajax al hacer enter que se añaden a la tabla, y como los mandas al ajax también

Comment: @HammerffallBK Listo hermano, cabe destacar que el archivo html no está bien indentado aquí y es demasiado código para formatearlo con este editor jajaja, Añadi el formulario de compra y la tabla donde se adicionan los productos, no añadí lo demás pues es mucho código.

Comment: @HammerffallBK Otro comportamiento extraño que veo es que si después de añadir productos a la tabla html y limpio los campos, al realizar la compra los valores en la base de datos son vacíos, por qué sucede esto¿?

Comment: @HammerffallBK Uso la plantilla adminLTE por si quieres replicarlo con más exactitud, no se si te sirva con eso que te pasé. Espero tu respuesta bro, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es lo preciso, pero puedes darte una idea

Dada la siguiente fila

```
var fila = '<tr id="row' + i + '"> <td>' + nit + '</td>'+
'<td>' + codProd + '</td> <td>' + descProd + '</td>'+
'<td>' + qty + '</td> <td>' + price + '</td>' + 
'<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i> Eliminar</button></td></tr>'; //esto seria lo que contendria la fila
```

puedes dejarlo de la siguiente manera

```
var fila = '<tr id="row' + i + '">'+
'<td>' + nit + ' </td>'+
'<td><input type="hidden" name="productosId[]" value="'+codProd+'" />' + codProd + '</td>'+
'<td><input type="hidden" name="descripcion[]" value="'+descProd+'" />' + descProd + '</td>'+
'<td><input type="hidden" name="cantidades[]" value="'+qty+'" />' + qty + '</td>'+
'<td><input type="hidden" name="precios[]" value="'+price+'" />' + price + '</td>' + 
'<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i> Eliminar</button></td></tr>'; //esto seria lo que contendria la fila
```

Con esto agregamos más campos al formulario, en forma de arreglo, esto quiere decir que podremos leer de `$_POST` el arreglo de productosId

Para fines practicos la tabla de transacción no debería de llevar los campos de PRODUCTO, CANTIDA ni PRECIOU
no se porque lo tengas así, pero dada la insercción de la transacción, puedes insertas los productos de la siguiente manera

```
// aqui se insertaria la transacción

$sql = "INSERT INTO transacciones VALUES(.......)";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

// obtenemos el id de la transacción insertada, 
$idTransaccion = mysqli_insert_id($link);
$productoId = 0;
$descripcion = 0; // es el nombre del producto
$cantidad = 0;
$precio = 0;
//Insertariamos los movimientos de la transacción obteniendo los datos de los productos uno por uno
// suponiendo que tu tabla de movimientos tenga los campos id(auto_increment), idtransaccion, productoid, cantidad, descripcion y precio
// y todos los campos son enteros o flotantes
// http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php
// http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO movimientos VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('iiidd', $idTransaccion, $productoId, $cantidad, descripcion, $precio); // 
foreach($_POST['productosId'] as $key => productoId) {
    $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'][$key];
    $cantidad = $_POST['cantidades'][$key];
    $precio = $_POST['precios'][$key];

    $stmt->execute();
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Bro, ya procedo a probar y si funciona lo asignaré como respuesta correcta, gracias por tu tiempo :D. Postearé la solución para todos cuando funcione!

Comment: No te preocupes, la idea es que entiendas que es lo que se trata de hacer, recolectar los datos como un arreglo.

Comment: Gracias @Hammerfall Bk, no entiendo porque le siguen dando dislike a la pregunta...

Comment: Amigo disculpa otra vez, se me olvidó mencionar que los codigos de productos no son todos iguales, puesto que son codigos de barras y son de hasta 30 números, por lo tanto ¿seguiría quedando esta linea asi

foreach($_POST['productosId'] as $key => $productoId) {
    $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'][$key];
    $cantidad = $_POST['cantidades'][$key];
    $precio = $_POST['precios'][$key];
} ?

Comment: Si el código de producto es un entero, si puede quedarse así. Si el código de producto es una cadena, deberías cambiar a linea del `bind_param` de esta manera `$stmt->bind_param('isidd', $idTransaccion, $productoId, $cantidad, descripcion, $precio);`